# Multiple relations to same model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a many-to-many relationship in Eloquent.

Schema:

```
templates       modules         module_template
- id            - id            - module_id
- name          - content       - template_id
                                - order
```

However, I need to make it possible for a single template to include the same module multiple times. How would I do that?

Example `module_template`:

```
module_id | template_id | order
1         | 42          | 1
4         | 42          | 2
1         | 42          | 3
```

---

`$template->modules()->detach($moduleId)` would [detach](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_detach) all relations to the model, right? Assuming it would even be possible to `attach` them in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `attach` multiple times, no problem with that. However `detach` will remove all the associations. (Of course your table can't have `FK1,FK2` unique/primary constraint applied)

But, fear not :) You can still do it manually:

```php
$moduleId = 1;

$template->modules()
   ->newPivotStatementForId($moduleId)
   ->where('order', 3)
   ->delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do that if you define module_template as its own Eloquent Model `ModuleTemplate`

That way you can insert and remove rows in the table without relying on the attach() and detach() and their checks.